# tex.runtoks: uniqueness of the <token register>

Tags: luatex, token-lists, registers

`tex.runtoks` can be used to execute instructions immediately.

```
\directlua{
  tex.settoks(421,'ABCDE');
  tex.runtoks(421)
}
```

Here `421` should be replaced by a unique private number, in LaTeX we could have

```
\newtoks\MyToks
\MyToks{ABCDE}
\the\MyToks
```

It happens that the meaning of `\MyToks` is `\toks17`, and 421 could be replaced by 17. But what is the correct way to retrieve this 17 ?

Comment: you can give the name `tex.settoks('MyToks','ABCDE');`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thx, does it work with `tex.scantoks`? I get errors when I try.

Comment: If you want to just have a unique number and not interact with an existing token register, then why are you using a token register at all?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger You mean `tex.runtoks` with a function? I am currently investigating both approaches...

Comment: Answer to my own question above: the semantic signature is `tex.scantoks(<toks register>, <catcode table number>, <string>)`